# How to close Hamburger menu with close icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set up a hamburger menu with a close icon already. I'm just not sure how to just turn off the hamburger menu with a simple click. Only thing I've been able to do is just reload the page completely. Perhaps there is some jquery that could be used to solve this issue.

The close menu button is item 1 in the menu list.

Here is my code.

```
    <div class="menu-wrapper">

  <nav>

    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>

<ul class="header-menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="close-menu"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></a></li>
  <li class="current"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="store.html">Prints</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="tutorial.html">Tutorials</a></li>
  <li><a href="sports.html">Sports</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #menu-icon {
  display: hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(../img/menu-icon.png) center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#close-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

```
  #menu-icon {

display:inline-block;
z-index: 10000;
}

  #close-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black !important;
      font-size: 20px !important;
  }
```

Comment: Well let's think about the process. You need to listen for a click event on the element, then 'close' the menu - whatever that means for you (for example, adding a `.close` class to it.) Try something...

Comment: I should add I'm a beginner. This is my first project. I will google all of that then.

Comment: That's fine, and we'll gladly help if you try something and run into problems.

Comment: I've been looking around and unsure of what the best practice is. I've managed to find something along the lines of this but I'm doing it wrong:

document.getElementById("close-menu").addEventListener("click", closeWindow);

function closeWindow() {
  document.getElementById('close-menu').innerHTML = close();
}

Comment: Always check the error console. Assigning the return value of `close()` (whatever that may be) as the `innerHTML` of your link won't do anything to close your menu. You have to first establish what 'closing' it means. Do you have a CSS class that, when active, puts the menu into a closed state? If so, the job of your event callback is to add that class. Conversely, when opening the menu, the class should be removed.

Comment: The CSS I have for the menu is that it the display is hidden unless in mobile view and when in mobile view the display is inline-block. Really though I am a beginner I'm really unsure what I'm supposed to be searching for here.

Comment: Could you add your CSS script?

Comment: Hello, updated above

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's an example of how to make a burger nav. **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxhqswc5)**

HTML:

```
<nav data-state=closed>
    <a>&times;</a>
    <a href=something.html>Link 1</a>
    <a href=something-else.html>Link 2</a>
    <a href=etc.html>Link 3</a>
</nav>
```

See how we're preparing to toggle the open/closed state with a data attribute. (We could have used a class, but I prefer a DA in this case because it means we can toggle it; with a class, you'd have to remove one class and add anothe, e.g. remove 'closed' and add 'open'.)

The structure is simple; we use a `nav` element and use the first `a` within it as the close icon. We use the multiplication (times) entity for this.

CSS:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #d55 !important;
}
nav[data-state=closed] {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/220px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png') no-repeat 100%/100%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
nav a { display: block; }
nav a:not(:first-of-type) { border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2); padding: .8rem 0; }
nav[data-state=closed] * { display: none; }
nav a:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    right: .2rem;
    top: -.1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now here's the key part, the JS:

```
//get nav element
let nav = $('nav');

//listen for clicks on it
nav.on('click', evt => {

    //...get current state (open vs. closed)
    let curr_state = nav.attr('data-state');

    //...if open, and click was NOT to close icon (first A tag) ignore click
    if (curr_state == 'open' && !$(evt.target).is('a:first-of-type')) return;

    //...otherwise toggle state (open it or close it)
    nav.attr('data-state', curr_state == 'closed' ? 'open' : 'closed');
})
```